# PHP round to integer

Tags: php, floating-point, integer, rounding

I want to round a number and I need a proper integer because I want to use it as an array key. The first "solution" that comes to mind is:

```
$key = (int)round($number)
```

However, I am unsure if this will always work. As far as I know `(int)` just truncates any decimals and since `round($number)` returns a float with theoretically limited precision, is it possible that `round($number)` returns something like 7.999999... and then `$key` is 7 instead of 8?

If this problem actually exists (I don't know how to test for it), how can it be solved? Maybe:

```
$key = (int)(round($number) + 0.0000000000000000001) // number of zeros chosen arbitrarily
```

Is there a better solution than this?

Comment: Integers stored within floats are always accurate, up to around 2^51, which is much more than can be stored in an `int` anyway. You are worrying over nothing.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Oops, I actually knew that (from Javascript) but didn't make the connection. You should make that an answer. BTW, in JS it's 2^53-1 iirc.

Comment: When you use rounded numbers as key, you run in trouble if you have more then one 7.x numbers with the rounded result of 8.

Comment: @u-nik It's exactly my intention that 7.4 and 7.6 end up with the same key. :)

Comment: There are three functions to handle rounding numbers: round, [ceil][] (round up), [floor][] (round down). I'm unsure which one you want to use. [ceil]: https://secure.php.net/ceil
[floor]: https://secure.php.net/floor

Comment: Then go on with `floor` or `ceil` :-)

Comment: Can someone please create an answer from @NiettheDarkAbsol's comment, otherwise I will. :)

Comment: From: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php ->
`echo (int) ( (0.1+0.7) * 10 ); // echoes 7!`
So it looks like it's actually not safe to cast (float) to (int), as it doesn't round and discards the floating point.
@AndreKR It looks like it's not safe to cast (float) to (int). What do you think?

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue Casting float to int is not generally safe, but it *is* safe to cast *the result of round()* to int, as long as that result is less than 2^51.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To round floats properly, you can use:

- [`ceil($number)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php): round up
- [`round($number, 0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php): round to the nearest integer
- [`floor($number)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php): round down

Those functions return float, but from [Niet the Dark Absol comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746283/php-round-to-integer): *"Integers stored within floats are always accurate, up to around 2^51, which is much more than can be stored in an int anyway."*

Answer (score 8):

`round()`, without a precision set always rounds to the nearest whole number. By default, round rounds to zero decimal places.

So:

```
$int = 8.998988776636;
round($int) //Will always be 9

$int = 8.344473773737377474;
round($int) //will always be 8
```

So, if your goal is to use this as a key for an array, this should be fine.

You can, of course, use modes and precision to specify exactly how you want `round()` to behave. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

**UPDATE**

You might actually be more interested in [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
echo intval(round(4.7)); //returns int 5
echo intval(round(4.3)); // returns int 4
```

Comment: Nope, `intval(4.7) == 4`, which is not what I want.

Comment: Yea, with `intval` by itself. Combine it with `round`. I've updated my answer

Comment: That suffers from the same (non-)problem that I described.

Answer (score 4):

What about simply adding 1/2 before casting to an int?

eg:

```
$int = (int) ($float + 0.5);
```

This should give a predictable result.

Comment: why only three upvotes? I mean, yes, 2^51 as described in accepted answer is a lot, but still this technique is even more correct, right?

Answer (score 2):

> For My Case, I have to make whole number by float or decimal type
> number. By these way i solved my problem. Hope It works For You.

```
$value1 = "46.2";
$value2 = "46.8";


// If we print by round()
echo round( $value1 );    //return float 46.0
echo round( $value2 );    //return float 47.0


// To Get the integer value
echo intval(round( $value1 ));   // return int 46
echo intval(round( $value2 ));   // return int 47
```

Comment: Please comment if have any Issue with the code. will try to update for better understand.

Answer (score 1):

Integers stored within floats are always accurate, up to around 2<sup>53</sup>, which is much more than can be stored in an int anyway. I am worrying over nothing.

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
function money_round(float $val, int $precision = 0): float|int
{
    $pow = pow(10, $precision);

    $result = (float)(intval((string)($val * $pow)) / $pow);
    if (str_contains((string)$result, '.')) {
        return (float)(intval((string)($val * $pow)) / $pow);
    }
    else {
        return (int)(intval((string)($val * $pow)) / $pow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide an explanation for your code.

Answer (score -3):

Round to the nearest integer

$key = round($number, 0);

Comment: It returns a float.

Comment: How about $key = intval(round($number, 0)) or $key = (int)round($number, 0)

Comment: Did you even *read* my question? I specifically gave `(int)round($number)` as an example of what I thought is *not* enough.